# Importing Multiple Text Files as Individual data.frames in R - 2.15.2 on Mac - 10.8.4

Tags: r, loops, import, text-files

I have searched through this forum for most of the day trying to find the solution - I could not find so I am posting. If the answer is already out there please point me in the right direction.

What I have - 
A directory with 40 texts files called the following

- test_63x_disc_z00.txt
- *01.txt
- *02.txt
- ...
- *39.txt

In each of these files there are 10 columns of data with no header and a varying number of rows.

What I want -
I want to have an individual data.frame in R for each text file with names:

- file00
- file01
- ...
- file39.

I then want to do add a header column to each of these data.frames.

I then want to be able to manipulate the data at ease (this last part I can sort out once I have input a the data)

This is what I have accomplished (don't laugh now) -

I can input a single text file as a data frame and add a header, like so :

```
d<-read.delim("test_63x_disc_z00.txt", header = F)

colnames(d)<-c("cell","CentX","CentY","CountLabels","AvgGreen","DeviationsGreen","AvgRed","DeviationsRed","GUI-ID","Slice")
```

I am not sure how to set up a loop to perform each of the commands to all 40 files and maintain distinct file names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To quicly read in a lot of data frames you can

```
 listy <- apply(data.frame(list.files()),  1, read.table, sep="", header=F)
```

Then to name them the list items, you can:

```
 names(listy) <- paste0("file", seq_along(1:40))
```

They are then called by listy$file1 etc.

Comment: Pepsimax, I can now see all of my data. When I do 'str(listy)' I see a separate list for each text file -great! However, I do not know how to access a specific text file. For example, if I want to look at just file1 how can I print it and then one step deeper how do I look at column 1 in file1 and so forth? This is going to lead to data manipulation and plotting, but I figure if I know how to access specific data I can slowly figure out the rest. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, sorry about taking so long to reply, I was on holiday in CERN! If you still have a problem, to access say the first column (if it has a header "name") of the first file/dataframe you can say listy$file$name. Similarly, column 2 of file 3 would be listy$file3$Column3Name. You can end this active question btw by marking one of the answers as correct by selecting the tick beside it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Metrics for editing my input code... I wasn't sure how to give it the format you did.

So I figured it out (dirty version), but it still needs work -

```
stem <- c("/Users/stefanzdraljevic/Northwestern/2013/Carthew-Rotation/Sample-Images-Ritika/ritika-tes/statistics3/test_63x_disc_z")
```

The above is the stem for the file naming`

```
addition <- c("00","01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31","34","35","36","37","38","39")
```

This will add the number of the text file to the end of stem. I am not sure how to incorporate the "00" numbering structure without writing them all out.

```
colnames <- c("cell","CentX","CentY","CountLabels","AvgGreen","DeviationsGreen","AvgRed","DeviationsRed","GUI-ID","Slice")
```

This will add column names to the data.frame

```
    data = NULL
for(j in stem){
    data[[j]] = NULL
    for(i in addition){
        data[[j]][[i]] = read.table(paste(j,i,".txt",sep=""), header=F, col.names=colnames)
    }
}
```

This loop does the trick.