# Importing multiple textfiles in R (with a twist)

Tags: r

Good day,

i have 33 *.tsv (tabbed delimited) in a directory. All files have the same row.names, but different columns. 
I want to simulteanously import all files, and the final product should be a list of 33 dataframes (or matrices) with names according to their file names.

1. `data <-lapply(dir(), read.table)` is not working as intended. The resulting list entries are factors due to row.names.
2. `data <- lapply(dir(), read.table, row.names=1, header = TRUE, sep = "\t", dec = ".")` does not work, because of double row.names errors.

The same is true when applying a solution presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18993672/importing-multiple-text-files-as-individual-data-frames-in-r-2-15-2-on-mac-1).

Another option would be the import of a big single file and then split into 33 objects by header names (who are separated by _1, _2, _3, and so on (also including character strings after the underscore).

Any help is appreciated as usual.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "does not work"

Comment: oh, i am getting a list for sure, but the content of the list is all factors because of the presence of the row.names in the original files.

Comment: Use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in the `read.table()`.

Answer (score 0):

Not very elegant, but how about

```
data <- lapply(dir(), read.table, header = TRUE, sep = "\t", dec = ".")
data <- lapply(data, function(x) rownames(x) <- x[,1] )
```

Comment: it will give the double row.names error again after the second line. the traceback tells me, 3 `rownames<-(`*tmp*`, value = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,  ... 
2 FUN(X[[26L]], ...) 
1 lapply(data, function(x) rownames(x) <- x[, 1])`

Comment: I dont know where the NAs are coming from. there are no NAs in the input files.

Comment: what does str(data[[1]]) give?

Comment: 'data.frame': 2019 obs. of  368 variables:
 $ ID         : chr  "FJ466152_1" "AF523898_1" "FJ466174_1" "GQ402593_1" ...
 $ JN178216_10: num  81.6 81.8 82.4 82.4 82.3 82.2 82.2 82.4 81.5 81.3 ..` and so on.

Comment: Weird...Does the following work? `rownames(data[[1]]) <- data[[1]][,1]`

Comment: It doesnt give an error, but it doesnt seem to do anything to the list

Comment: Maybe look at it for a few files before reading all of them. `d <- read.table(dir()[1], header = TRUE, sep = "\t", dec = ".")` and `str(d)` and `rownames(d) <- d[1]`

Comment: i will. did it only for the first, and it didnt give any problems